# Java - Display Windows -1252 Characters in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to display some Windows-1252 characters by taking their numeric equivalent as input from the user in Java (using Eclipse). I am expecting the character to be displayed as in the link: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ansi.asp

I tried with numeric values 152 and 149 but they are displayed as question marks in Eclipse console. My code in Eclipse:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Encoding_CP1252 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        int a = in.nextInt();   
        System.out.println("You Entered: " +a);
        char b = (char) a;
        System.out.println("Windows-1252 equivalent is: "+b);
    }
}
```

I even tried to tweak the Eclipse configuration in Run--> Run Configuration --> Common tab --> Encoding set to 'Default -inherited (Cp1252)' but still the same result.

Comment: Try in native console insteed of eclipse's

Comment: Set `UTF-8` encoding in eclipse preferences and you'll see all symbols

Comment: Setting UTF-8 displays blank for input 149 and 152.

Comment: Native console also displays ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [The char data type [...] are based on the original Unicode specification, which defined characters as fixed-width 16-bit entities.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)

Because of this `char b = (char) a;` does not work and you have to use [`new String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.lang.String-) instead:

```
...
byte[] b = {(byte) a};
System.out.println("Windows-1252 equivalent is: "+ new String(b, "Windows-1252"));
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine. For others, added the code to do the reverse as well: `int a = 152;   
        //System.out.println("You Entered: " + a);
        byte[] b = {(byte) a};
        String d =new String(b, "Windows-1252");
        System.out.println(d);
        
        byte[] c = d.getBytes("Windows-1252");
        int i = c[0];
        System.out.println(i&255);`